# Hash (MD5) an incremental list to provide individual hash values

Tags: python, list, hash, md5

I'm hoping that somebody could help me.  I'm really new to scripting. I'm not trying to reverse hash anything but I am interested in trying to generate a numeric list from 0 to 1000 and then obtain the MD5 for each number.

I appreciate that this sounds very simple.  I've managed to generate a txt file with the list but I can't seem to get the numbers on individual lines which I could then hash using the likes of md5deep.

If anyone could help me out I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Can you show us your code, a sample of the result that is being produced so far, and a sample of the result that you'd like to produce?

Answer (score 1):

I am not clear what your exact problem is from the question, it sounds like you have a few options.  Here is a pure shell/python solution

Pure python:

```
import hashlib
for i in xrange(1, 1001):
    print hashlib.md5(str(i)).hexdigest()
```

Output

```
c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b
c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c
  ...
b706835de79a2b4e80506f582af3676a
a9b7ba70783b617e9998dc4dd82eb3c5
```

Pure shell (here shown on osx, similar on linux)

```
seq 1 1000 | xargs -I {} md5 -s "{}"
```

Output

```
MD5 ("1") = c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b
MD5 ("2") = c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c
  ...
MD5 ("999") = b706835de79a2b4e80506f582af3676a
MD5 ("1000") = a9b7ba70783b617e9998dc4dd82eb3c5
```